# Which agave species are small enough for my succulent garden?

Tags: succulents, outdoor, design

Two years ago, I have made two succulent garden plots, each lies in the bare center of a fruit tree garden bed. The central area receives enough sun for socculents. I have planted cacti, Sansevierias and Echeverias.

The overall outcome was very good, except for one factor - hail.
My Echeverias have fared well the previous winter and new leaves took over and completely replaced the damaged leaves. However, this winter I had a single, yet strong hail storm which was catastrophic to few of them. Though I expect my Echeverias to recover, I plant to move them to a more protected area.

I have considered several solutions. One of them was replacing the Echeverias with small Agaves to keep the same visual effect. Which Agaves species should I use? Here are my selection criteria:

1- Small Agaves only, with top size around 12" give or take. No A. Americana or something of that size. There is just no room for monsters with daggers :)

2- Not too slow-growing: This is to allow Agaves planted in spring to have established a sturdy root system before the hot and dry summer.

3- Pups - Optional. This is a bonus, given that I intend to create a clumping effect, not an oversize effect. Extra pups will be potted and then sold/exchanged with friends. Some will be planted further away from the mother plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link for miniature agaves (really intended to be grown in pots)  might be helpful - you'll need to decide which will grow where you are, depending on your local climate and average winter temperatures, since you've not given that information https://www.houzz.com/magazine/10-small-scale-agaves-just-right-for-containers-stsetivw-vs~69485767

Comment: These would all grow in my country as I have a warm Mediterranean climate. Finding all of them won't be easy, but two look like what I already have. I'll print the page with the pictures and names. A nearby succulent grower may be able to help me find them.